# Number for each equation

Tags: equations

How can I give a new number to each equation?

```
\begin{equation}
    i_t = \sigma(W_{xi} * X_t + W_ {hi} * H_{t-1} + W_{ci} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)
    f_t = \sigma(W_{xf} * X_t + W_ {hf} * H_{t-1} + W_{cf} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
\end{equation}
```

Or is the only way to write each equation in a new function? In this case, how can I reduce the whitespace between each equation? And how can I align each equation?

```
\begin{equation}
    i_t = \sigma(W_{xi} * X_t + W_ {hi} * H_{t-1} + W_{ci} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f_t = \sigma(W_{xf} * X_t + W_ {hf} * H_{t-1} + W_{cf} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
\end{equation}
```

Comment: As pointed out in the answers, the `amsmath` package has useful commands and environments to use for such situations,  The `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsldoc`) is a useful source of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to switching from a pair of `equation` environments to a single `align` environment, as has already been suggested in [@Kersouman's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518645/5001), you may also want to (a) apply a few negative-thinspace kerning adjustments whenever `W` is followed by either `_x` or `_c` and (b) switch from `\mathit` (the default) to `\textit` whenever the subscript terms contain two or more letters.

[image]

Switching to `\textit` has a pronounced effect here because `\mathit{f}` takes up far more space than `\textit{f}` does.

A side-effect achieved by making these adjustments is that the two equations line up much more nicely than they do otherwise. While this extra alignment wasn't an objective when I started out making the adjustments, the outcome is presumably not unwelcome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment

\begin{document}
without any adjustments:
\begin{align}
  i_t &= \sigma(W_{xi} * X_t + W_{hi} * H_{t-1} + W_{ci} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
  f_t &= \sigma(W_{xf} * X_t + W_{hf} * H_{t-1} + W_{cf} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
\end{align}

with kerning adjustments and \verb+\textit+ instead of \verb+\mathit+:
\begin{align}
  i_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xi}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hi}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{ci}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
  f_t &= \sigma(W_{\!\textit{xf}} * X_t + W_{\textit{hf}} * H_{t-1} + W_{\!\textit{cf}} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, i never noticed the alignment on the operations

Comment: does it only apply to the letter W? what if its S_ij?

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the `gather` environment from the `amsmath` package if you just want to number each one of your equations or the `align` environment from the same package if you want to add some alignment (for example, around the `=` symbol):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gather}
        i_t = \sigma(W_{xi} * X_t + W_ {hi} * H_{t-1} + W_{ci} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
        f_t = \sigma(W_{xf} * X_t + W_ {hf} * H_{t-1} + W_{cf} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
    \end{gather}

    \begin{align}
        i_t & = \sigma(W_{xi} * X_t + W_ {hi} * H_{t-1} + W_{ci} \circ C_{t-1} + b_i)\\
        f_t & = \sigma(W_{xf} * X_t + W_ {hf} * H_{t-1} + W_{cf} \circ C_{t-1} + b_f)
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```